# Monitor scrambling

Tags: monitor

I have a HP desktop that I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on.  It is hooked up to a Samsung monitor.  Everything has been fine for a month (since installation) but suddenly the monitor is scrambling while on the internet and videos will not work.  I have tried different cables, a different monitor, uninstalling and reinstalling Google Chrome and checked drivers.  I cannot figure it out.  Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few people are having issues with Chrome Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (64-bit), Ubuntu 22.04,  try unchecking the Hardware Acceleration in chrome://settings/system  and relaunching